# Permission denied...?

Tags: apt

I tried apt-get update and upgrade together and this is what I got.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What should I do?

Comment: Whoopsie, didn't see that question was there already

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `sudo`?

Updating applications requires you to use administrative powers, which for security reasons are locked behind `sudo`.

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and enter your password to upgrade your programs.

Answer (score 1):

To run both `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` you need superuser privilege. You can run these together as,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And obviously you need to give your administrative password.

Answer (score 0):

The command `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` requires you to be a root.

You have to do this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you are prompted to enter your password. Enter it and enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to superuser privilege to run these...
Then, you should be superuser.. To be Superuser.. you should add "Sudo" to these commands.

Try this...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And if it is asking a password, Then, Give your Password And Hit the Enter button..